# What would be a good way to access a global variable in a model in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
```

The two lines of code above let me use configuration to access my global variable but I need to do the same in my model to test if an input should be required.

What would be the equivalent of these lines to behave this line below work?

```
Configuration.GetSection("privacy")["GDPR"]
```

or

```
public bool TempBool => Convert.ToBoolean(_configuration["privacy:GDPR"]);
```

This is what I have going on so far and it is not going to work because of the public register model.

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public RegisterModel(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}

public bool TempBool => Convert.ToBoolean(_configuration["privacy:GDPR"]);

[Compare(nameof(TempBool), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RegisterModelConsentErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
[Display(Name = "RegisterModelConsentDisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
public bool Consent { get; set; }
```

Please let me know if anyone has any question about what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: What does your controller constructor and action look like? Typically you only ask for a `IConfiguration` in a DI Service's constructor, not a POCO model.

Comment: Are you using **ASP.NET** (for the full, classic .NET framework) - or **ASP.NET Core** ?? You have both tags which makes it a bit tricky to know what we're dealing with here.....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo:

Controller:

```
public class Test2Controller : Controller
    {
        IConfiguration _Configuration;
        public Test2Controller(IConfiguration Configuration) {
            _Configuration = Configuration;
        }
        public IActionResult TestIConfiguration() {
            RegisterModel r = new RegisterModel(_Configuration);
            return Ok(r.TempBool);
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
public class RegisterModel {
        public RegisterModel(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            TempBool = Convert.ToBoolean(configuration["privacy:GDPR"]);
        }

        public bool TempBool { get; set; }

        [Compare(nameof(TempBool), ErrorMessageResourceName = "RegisterModelConsentErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
        [Display(Name = "RegisterModelConsentDisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(SharedResource))]
        public bool Consent { get; set; }
    }
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  ...
  "privacy": {
    "GDPR": true
  }
}
```

result:
[image]